# База данных sql, необходимо сделать запрос в бд SELECT WHERE переменная

Tags: c#, sql

Доброго всем времени суток, нужно составить запрос и вывести результат в `DataGridView`:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, FIO, bolnichniy, otpusk, zasvoischet, kurs FROM Juniary WHERE FIO = @FIO", connectionString);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIO", comboBox2.GetItemText(comboBox2.SelectedItem));
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataTable table = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter1.Fill(table);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

в чем беда? неправильный запрос или данны не попадают в table?

Comment: Этот код не работает? Как вы поняли, что он не работает?

Comment: Он выводит мне название столбцов но не строку которую я бы хотел найти по столбцу FIO

Comment: Читайте документацию https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=net-7.0#system-data-common-dbdataadapter-fill(system-data-datatable) Но скорее всего запрос вернул 0 строк. Не используйте `AddWithValue`, используйте `Add` с указанием типа поля БД.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить этот запрос отдельно в самой БД

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Эм бьет ошибку потому что не знает что за переменная @FIO

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@FIO".

Comment: по суть мой вопрос заключается как поместить переменную в запрос?

Comment: Потому что то как я это сделал, явно не работает

Comment: SELECT * FROM Juniary WHERE FIO он даже строгим запросом почему-то не  выводим строку

Comment: Давайте начнем с того, что вы расскажете, а что за база данных?

Comment: Запрос на базе отдельно выполняется подстановкой вместо @FIO реального значения. Это как бы логично, не?

Comment: база сотрудников по отделениям за последний год, нужно будет расчитывать нагрузку. Значения я подставил фактическое но он все равно ругается, из-за того что 3 слова получается хоть я и беру их в кавычки, сейчас решил попробовать добавить просто новый параметр код_сотрудника и по нему искать их а не по фио.

Comment: База данных из Visual studio построеная на службах

Comment: MS SQL? или что? Сервер БД какой?

Comment: Та все я уже разобрался, не знаю как обьяснить посмотрите в интернете, вы добавляете файл с базой данных в проект и он открывается как подключенные данные через конструктор в visual studio там и запросы можно писать, не могу ответить какой там сервер.